# On a trip to Belgium, should I stay in Bruges or Ghent?

Tags: belgium, ghent, bruges

I will have about 4-6 days in Belgium (in August) with my father, who is in his 60s. He is not a big city person. We will be coming in from London, and after Belgium we will be staying a day or two in Mannheim.

I feel that Bruges or Ghent or both would be better choices to avoid the "big city" of Brussels. However, I've seen multiple pieces of advice that indicates they are "day-trip" cities. How can I determine which would be the better one for us to stay in?

Comment: Yes, and if one of the cities is "too small to stay for  more than a day or two"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both cities are really interesting destinations. The question to distinct between the two is whether or not you like tourist spots. Bruges is the more touristic city of the two. Personally I would go ofr Ghent and do a day trip to Bruges. But the other way around is perfectly possible.

However if you really would like to escape the crowds, go to Lier or Hasselt. No tourists and really pearls to visit.

Comment: Are there buses that will do a day tour of the other?

Comment: Monksy they are a 30 min train drive away from each other

Comment: You will have to plan it yourself. However, as said, G(h)ent en Bruges (Brugge) are really close to eachother. You can easily go by train (they are each other's next stops). I prefer G(h)ent as well above Bruges. Perhaps that is because I am from G(h)ent myself. Feel free to ask more questions about this.

Comment: In Bruges: Bring sandwiches and packed lunch with you. The town is Expensive with a capital E.